# Pass TreeMap value to Toolbar Title in second activity

Tags: android, listview, treemap

I have a TreeMap with a ListView, I want the second activity to take the selected item of the ListView and use it as the Title of the second activity.
(Using Strings or Arrays instead of TreeMap I can make it work, but then the TextWatcher won't work, and using TreeMap the TextWatcher works fine).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    EditText buscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busqueda);
    TreeMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new TreeMap<>();

    nameAddresses.put   (   "Coso",                     "Desear       " );
    nameAddresses.put   (   "бажа́ти",                  "Desear       " );
    nameAddresses.put   (   "бала́кати",                "Charlar          " );


    final List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});

    Iterator it = nameAddresses.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
        resultsMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
        listItems.add(resultsMap);
    }


    resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    resultsListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);


    resultsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("Want to Pass", resultsListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the main activity, and now the second:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
TextView mTextView;
TextView mTextView2;
ImageButton button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    //changing statusbar color
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    button = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.imageButton);




    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();      


    if (bundle != null) {                         

        mToolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("Want to Pass"));   





        if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Coso")) {           писа́ти
            mToolbar.setSubtitle("Escribir");
```

The `ListView` shows two elements in each item ("Coso and Desear" for example) and I want either of these two to be used as Title in the `toolBar` of the second activity........